# datarow filtering array with dataset c# asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, dataview

I have this page of operators that has two tables with data from database, one table with existing operators and one table with existing users. If a user is already an operator, I want that row to be hidden in the table. Here is my code:

C#:

```
        var userDetailsList = new List<ContactPartial>();
        TellusAPI.TellusUserDetails userDetails;

        var operators = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId); //DataSet
        var getUser = webSearch.DoSearchForNameAndNumber(userId, txtSearchForOperator.Text, false, "", "", false, false, out userDetails); //Array

        if (getUser == null)
        {
            userDetailsList.Add(new ContactPartial(userDetails));
            rptAdd.DataSource = null;
        }

        else
        {
            userDetailsList = getUser.Select(x => new ContactPartial(x)).ToList();

            var dv = new DataView(operators.Tables[0]);

            foreach (var Operator in userDetailsList)
            {
                if (!userDetailsList.Contains(Operator)) continue;
                dv.RowFilter = "ID = " + Operator.Id;
            }

            rptAdd.DataSource = userDetailsList; //Repeater
        }
```

Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for converting.
/// </summary>
public class ContactPartial
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ContactPartial(TellusUserDetails tud)
    {
        if (tud == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Id = tud.UserID;
        FirstName = tud.FirstName;
        LastName = tud.LastName;
        CompanyName = tud.Organisation.Description;
        Email = tud.Email;
    }

    public ContactPartial(TellusSearchUserInfo tsi)
    {
        if (tsi == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Id = tsi.ID;
        FirstName = tsi.FirstName;
        LastName = tsi.LastName;
        CompanyName = tsi.CompanyName;
        Email = tsi.Email;
    }
}
```

So I now compare these two and filter the rows with ID, but it still reads all rows.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected result and some explanation in your code about which line does what and does not do what is expected ?

Comment: The expected result is that when you search for users in database, you want to filter out those that already contains in operators table. I have the ID that should know that.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Read comment please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (var Operator in userDetailsList) ******
        {
            if (!userDetailsList.Contains(Operator)) continue;
            dv.RowFilter = "ID = " + Operator.Id;
        }
```

I see some problem with naming convention .. You should corretly notify what is operator and what is user details object. Don't mix them up.

```
        foreach (var user in userDetailsList)
        {
            // Since dv is the one which contain operator details
           if (dv.Select("ID= '" + user.Id + "'").Count > 0)
           {
            dv.RowFilter = "ID = " + user.Id;
           }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah your code is not correct, I cannot use `dv.Select` since there is no Select for `DataView` in IntelliSense.

Comment: you can use the dv.Table.Select